# Showing post according to post dates

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins, custom-post-type

i have one event plug-in and now i want to show my event post like current events,upcoming events then past events.i have created one custom post for this and create 2 meta-boxes for start date and end date. But now how i call?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, I just can say you'll probably need to perform a query similar to this one:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'end_date',

    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'      => 'endt_date',
            'value'    => time(),
            'type'     => 'numeric',
            'compare'  => '<'
        )
    )
);

$past_events = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This would return the past events, assuming your post type is called `events`, you have a custom field `end_date` that stores a numeric timestamp...

You should modify the `meta_query` accordingly for current and past events, using different `value` and `compare` arguments.

Take a look at docs for [**WP_Query**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class and in particular to the **[Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)** section.